# how can I login with facebook from localhost. (Symfony)

Tags: facebook-login

I am using symfony. I have to create programme for facebook login. I created on class and in that create two function first is for generating link and other is callback function. 
     In controller created one action name is indexAction, in that object of class present. But when we run programme using link as http://localhost/symfony-demo-project/web/app_dev.php/login on browser it gives Error like:
    The autoloader expected class "Btit\Bundle\CommonBundle\facebook\facebookLogin" to be defined in file "/var/www/html/symfony-demo-project/src/Btit/Bundle/CommonBundle/facebook/facebookLogin.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

```
<?php

    namespace Btit\Bundle\CommomBundle\facebook;

    use Facebook\Facebook;


        $fb = new Facebook/Facebook([
                'app_id' => '1622871987981966',
                'app_secret' => '6a15b7ae9e4409b6d33553ed3ed61f95',
                'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
        ]);

        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

        $permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://localhost/symfony-demo-project/app-dev.php/login/', $permissions);

        echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';

    }

    function Callback()
    {
        $fb = new Facebook/Facebook([
                'app_id' => '1622871987981966',
                'app_secret' => '6a15b7ae9e4409b6d33553ed3ed61f95',
                'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
        ]);

        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

        try {
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

        if (! isset($accessToken)) {
            if ($helper->getError()) {
                header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
                echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
                echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
                echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
                echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
            } else {
                header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
                echo 'Bad request';
            }
            exit;
        }

        // Logged in
        echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
        var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

        // The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
        $tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
        echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
        var_dump($tokenMetadata);

        // Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
        $tokenMetadata->validateAppId($config['app_id']);
        // If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
        //$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
        $tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

        if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
            // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
            try {
                $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
            } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
                exit;
            }

            echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
            var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
        }

        $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
        // You can redirect them to a members-only page.
        //header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');
    }

    }
    ?>
```

Controller is like that

```
<?php

namespace Btit\Bundle\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use Btit\Bundle\CommonBundle\facebook\facebookLogin;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $l = new facebookLogin;
        $l->LoginLink();
        $l->Callback();
        //return array();

    }   

}
?>
```

Give me solution for this error...